# How to broadcast the RabbitMQ message to all listeners using Spring Streams

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, messaging, spring-cloud-stream

I need to consume some message on all available Rabbit MQ listeners using Spring Streams.

How can I do that?

At this time I found the way to do so if I remove the `group` from the binder. But 1) I'm not sure that is the right way 2) the message never removed from the queue and same time it never consumed by the newly added listeners.

Here is my current config:

```
spring:

  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        contentType: "application/json"
      bindings:
        broadcast-queue-in:
          destination: my
#          group: BroadcastQueue
      rabbit:
        default:
          consumer:
            queueNameGroupOnly: true
        bindings:
          broadcast-queue-in:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: 'BroadcastQueue'
```

To remove the message from the queue after some reasonable period (which could work for me) I tried:
`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.broadcast-queue-in.consumer.ttl: 30000`
and
`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.broadcast-queue-in.consumer.expire: 30000`

It does not help.

Also I tried to set the header of the message in the producer with appropriated expire and ttl. But that did not work as well.

Will appreciate any ideas on that. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the right approach is to use `fanout`exchange and separate queue per each consumer like described here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html
Now I need to find out how to do that with `Spring Cloud Stream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To broadcast the message you need to use `fanout` exchange.
Using the `Spring Cloud Stream` it as easy as just changing your configuration file.

For the producer you need something like:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        broadcast-queue-out:
           destination: broadcast-exchange-fanout
      rabbit:
        broadcast-queue-out:
          exchangeType: fanout
```

and for the consumers you need:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        broadcast-queue-in:
           destination: broadcast-exchange-fanout
           consumer:
             concurrency: 1
      rabbit:
        broadcast-queue-in:
          exchangeType: fanout
```

If you are using multiple threads for your consumers like:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        contentType: "application/json"
        consumer:
          concurrency: 4
```

It makes no sense to use that defaults for the fanout queues. It would be consumed by single thread anyway. So it make sense to override this default value and set it to 1.